# Needing assistance with this metric space question.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $Y$ be a subset of $X$.

(a) A subset $G$ of $Y$ is relatively open in $Y$ iff there is an open subset $U$ in $X$ with $G=U \cap Y$

**Attempt:**

If $G$ is a relatively open subset of $Y$, then $\forall y \in G,r_y>0$ s.t. $B_y(y;r_y)\subseteq G$. The book suggests that I am supposed to consider the union of open balls, $\bigcup \left \{ B(y;r_y):y \in G \right \}$.

Some help/hints/clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of relatively open? Is it a set $G$ in $(Y,\hat{d})$ is open in $Y$ if for all $y \in G$, there is an $\epsilon >0$ such that $B_\hat{d}(y,\epsilon) \subset G$ where $\hat{d} = d|_{Y\times Y}$?

Comment: Essentially, that some subsets of A that are not open subsets of the larger space may still be open subsets of A.

Comment: Yes, but is your definition of relatively open the one that I gave? Of course, if $Y$ is not open in $X$, then $Y$ will still be open in $Y$.

Comment: Yes, That looks correct.

Comment: $B_y$ denotes the open ball with respect to $d$ restricted to $Y$, right?

Comment: Yes, $B_y$ is restricted to $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is relatively open in $Y$, then for all $y \in G$ there is some $\varepsilon_y > 0$ such that $B_\hat{d}(y,\varepsilon_{y}) \subset G$. Then prove that $G = \bigcup_{y \in G} B_{\hat{d}}(y,\varepsilon_y)$. Then, in $X$, the set $U: = \bigcup_{y \in G} B_d(y,\varepsilon_y)$ is open in $X$ and $U\cap Y = G$.

Conversely, if $U$ is open in $X$, then for each $x \in U\cap Y$, there is an $\varepsilon_x >0$ such that $B_d(x,\varepsilon_x)\subset U$. Then, if $G=Y\cap U$, we have: $G = \bigcup_{x \in U\cap Y} B_{\hat{d}}(x,\varepsilon_x)$, so that $G$ is relatively open in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ a relatively open set in $Y$, that is an open set of the metric space $(Y,d_Y)$, where $d_Y$ is $d$ restricted to $Y\times Y$.

Let $U=\bigcup_{y\in G}B(y,r_y)$. Then $U$ is an open set of $(X,d)$ (union of open balls).

We also have:

$$U\cap Y=\left(\bigcup_{y\in G}B(y,r_y)\right)\cap Y=\bigcup_{y\in G}(B(y,r_y)\cap Y)$$

Then notice that $B(y,r_y)\cap Y=B_{d_Y}(y,r_y)$. Hence $U\cap Y=\bigcup_{y\in G}B_{d_Y}(y,r_y)=G$ (the last equality comes from the fact that $G$ is open in $(Y,d_Y)$).

Now let's assume that $G=U\cap Y$ with $U$ an open set of $(X,d)$ and let $y\in Y$. In particular, $y\in U$, so there exists $r_y>0$ such that $B(y,r_y)\subset U$. This implies that $B(y,r_y)\cap Y\subset G$. Once again, use the fact that $B(y,r_y)\cap Y=B_{d_Y}(y,r_y)$. So we proved that $G$ is an open set of $(Y,d_Y)$, so it's relatively open.

Comment: Very concise. Though I'm confused on why $B(y,r_y)$ which is an open ball for each in element in $U$ intersected with $Y$ is equivalent to $B_{dy}(y,r_y)$.

Comment: Let $y_1\in B(y,r_y)\cap Y$. We have $d(y,y_1)<r_y$, which is equivalent, as $y,y_1\in Y$, to $d_Y(y,y_1)<r_y$. So $y_1\in B_{d_Y}(y,r_y)$. For the other inclusion it's basically the same proof.

Comment: Ok, That makes sense.