# Open set in metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(X,d)$ a metric space, $Y \subset X, V \subset Y$. Show: $V$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $V= Y \cap U$, where $U$ is open in $X$.

I tried to use the neighborhood with for $x \in Y$ then $N^{Y}_r(x)=Y\cap N^{X}_r(x)$. Then I had no idea how to continue. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: For me, by definition $V$ is open in $Y$ if $V=Y\cap U$ for some open $U$ in $X$... It would be good if you can say your definition of open set

Comment: There is nothing to prove: this is a definition.

Comment: To clarify, cello means that $V$ is open if $V = Y \cap U$ for some open set $U$ is the usual definition of open in the metric subspace $Y$. Therefore, it is likely that you are working with a different, equivalent definition. What is the definition you were given?

Comment: This is a *metric space*.  So we restrict the metric to $Y$.  Then from that metric we define "open in $Y$".  Thus there is something to prove.  After we prove this, then it becomes natural to define a relative topology for a subset of a more general topological space using this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661542/needing-assistance-with-this-metric-space-question/1661581#1661581